# When trying to use SharedPreferences editor, I get Complete action using

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

In my application I need to save some values to the device,

I found that I can use SharedPreferences to do so.

This is how I do it:

```
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("ws_username",user.getUsername());
    editor.putString("ws_password",b);
    editor.putString("ws_email",user.getEmail());
    editor.commit();
```

By the way, I am saving the username and password because I want it so when you open up my app, it automaticly logs you in.. Is this a secure/correct place to save these values?

**This is not my question though**, The question/problem is that when this code runs, it opens up the Complete Action using... menu which contains all the activities that are installed on the phone (including wierd system ones).

Why is this happening, and how do I bypass it?

Comment: Cannot see how/why that piece of code would open the 'Complete action' options. Regarding security, if you a paranoid, you could do a something like hashing the values, I personally do not think it to be an issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, turns out it was a line that ran after this code which I didn't think could cause the problem..